# String functions to show a substring

Tags: c#

I have a string. If the length of the string is more than 90 characters i have to display only the 90 characters & concatenate it with a ".." can anyone tell me which string function i can use for this?

Comment: `string newstring = string.Substring(0,90)` + "...";` would give you that, Read the documentation [string.Substring(int,int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

```
if (myString.Length > 90)
{
    myString = myString.Substring(0, 90) + "..."
}
```

You should learn how to [work with strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in C#

Comment: What if i want to use it in the view of an ASP.net MVC app? I cant use +"..." there.

Comment: I haven't worked with ASP.NET. Try to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`, then you're able to use `Append()` method

Answer (score 1):

No out-of-the-box string functions for doing that exists in C# but you can write your own

```
public static String Truncate(String str)
{
    return str.Length > 90 ? str.Substring(0, 90) + "..." : str;
}
```

Comment: what if i want to use it in the view of an MVC app?

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = myString.Length > 90 ? myString.Substring(0, 90) + "..." : myString;
```